# Abs shower drain wtih 2 90° elbow to p-trap in shower drain

Tags: shower, drain, pvc, abs, p-trap

I am rebuilding shower, and i have a little issue with drain, I need to move it back and to left, the only way to do it as I figured it out it's to put 2 90° degree elbow together than in to p-trap,I have a picture, and pipe sticking out is part of P-trap I was gonna cut in down and add 2 90°elbows. I wonder if it's ok to do that? Or what my options could be here? [image]thank you for help and answers!!!+

Comment: 2-45 DEGREE BENDS MIGHT MAKE IT EASIER TO SNAKE IN THE FUTURE.

Comment: Thank you for response Jack, with 45° it will take more room so I have to raise the floor more,  i was trying to avoid that. Other than that should be fine you think?

Comment: I agree with jack2 45’s would be better , BUT.  I would dig it out and replumb trying to get a snake through 2 90’s or even 2 45’s and a trap ? This is why we add clean outs because each 90 makes it that much harder to clean out and with them that close they will build up soap and hair much faster. I am sure this is not what you are looking for in an answer. I would create my own drain pan and use tile. There is no problem with a drain not being centered in a shower , I have found the more off set in 1 corner or closer to 1 wall actually works quite well and consider rectangular drains also.